# Is there any way to increase the maximum number of alerts in Google?

Tags: google-alerts

I'm getting the following error when I'm trying to add a new alert:

> You have already subscribed to the maximum number of alerts. You must delete one of your current alerts before you can create this one. *Dismiss*

Is there any way of upgrading the limit? Or it's hardcoded by Google? Any workaround?

I'm already on paid 100GB plan. Would it change anything if I change to 1TB or 10TB plan?

Btw. I've already 1000 configured alerts.

Comment: By "100GB plan", do you mean a [Google Drive storage plan](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375123?hl=en)?

Comment: @Rubén Yes, I would expect to have some threshold increased by default. Or maybe having a business account would help? Unless the limits are hardcoded to whatever account you use.

Comment: Added a couple of notes to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK there is no way to increase the maximum number of alerts for a given account.

Alternatives

- Consolidate alerts (i.e. use the OR operator)
- Use a second account.

Notes:

- The [Google Drive storage plans](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375123?hl=en) only increase the storage limit, not other limits like the number of allowed alerts.
- [Google Apps for Work](https://www.google.com/work/apps/business/) doesn't increase the Google Alert limits.

**References**

- [Is there a maximum number of Google Alerts allowed per user? - Google Serch Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/websearch/4ffUBMuXMVg)
- [Search operators - Search Help](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?hl=en)